# Defining custom ActiveRecord creators through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have some models with a `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations between them similar to below:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes id, name, hash_salt etc
  has_many :contacts

end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes id, customer_id, email_hash, email etc
  belongs_to :customer

end
```

I would like to have a custom creator method to allow some logic to run looking for an existing record prior to creating a new object, similar to the following:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  class << self
    def find_or_create(customer_id, params = {})
      customer = Customer.find(customer_id)
      email_hash = SCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:email], customer.hash_salt)
      record = Contact.where(customer_id: customer_id).where(email_hash: email_hash).first
      if !record
        record = new(params)
      end

      record
    end
  end
end
```

If I am calling the custom creator through an association such as

```
cust = Customer.find(1)
cust.contacts.find_or_create(cust.id, contact_params)
```

is there any way that I can omit the `customer_id` param and fetch this from the caller somehow? I'm confused as to how Rails does this when I call `cust.contact.create(contact_params)`

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 3):

You have a few different things going on here, but I think the key piece you're after is how you can “extend” the association to define a custom method on the collection proxy. If that sounds greek, I have good news… it's really easy:

```
class Customer
  has_many :contacts do 
    def find_or_create(params = {})
      proxy_association.owner #=> Customer instance
    end
  end
end
```

This said, you  will probably want to refactor that `find_or_create` method on `Contact` so it's not doing so much.

```
class Customer
  has_many :contacts do
    def by_email(email)
      proxy_association.target.by_email proxy_association.owner.hashed_value(email)
    end
  end

  def hashed_value(value)
    SCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(value, hash_salt)
  end
end

class Contact
  scope :by_email, ->(email) { where(email_hash: email) }
end
```

Now you can get contacts like this:

```
@customer.contacts.by_email(params[:email])
```

Or you can check for existence like this:

```
@customer.contacts.by_email(params[:email]).any?
```

Since you've got this hashing precursor, an idempotent create is a little more challenging. Normally you can do this:

```
@customer.contacts.where(params).first_or_create
# won't work for your case
```

You need to pre-hash the email and remove it from the params in this case. You can probably extend the association with this as well, but here's the gist:

```
contact = @customer.contacts.by_email(params.delete(:email))
contact = contact.where(params).first_or_create
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use first_or_create while going through the associated rows. Try like this:-

```
cust.contacts.where(contact_params).first_or_create
```